# OpenCL - OpenGL Interop performance

Tags: performance, opengl, interop, opencl

I have a code where I create GL texture 8K(7680 x 4320) and I render to this texture. Then I switch it to CL and I do some stuff...

**Problem is that "switching" is very slow.**

If I don't run any CL code, only switch. It has around 40FPS on my GTS 450.

If I comment "clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects(..)" line => no switch. It has around 600FPS.

Is There some way how I can speed up?

I want to ask too If this is problem only with Nvidia or others like Ati, Intel and some SoC(ARM) have a same speed issue?

Creating GL-CL texture:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_fbo);
glGenTextures(1, &m_tex);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, m_imageSize.x, m_imageSize.y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_INT, NULL);        //GL_ALPHA
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_tex, 0);
if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)!=GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    return false;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

int err;
m_memD = clCreateFromGLTexture2D(ecl.getContext(), CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, m_tex, &err);
if(ERR_CL)
    return false;
```

GL - CL Interop:

```
void activateCL()
{
    glFinish();
    int err = clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects(m_queue, 1, &m_memD, 0, 0, 0);
}    
void activateGL()
{
    int err;
    err = clFinish(m_queue);
    err = clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects(m_queue, 1, &m_memD, 0, 0, 0);

}

bool activateGLRendering()
{
    activateGL();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);
    return true;
}
bool deactivateGLRendering()
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same similar question as asked in this thread: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492425/opencl-gl-interop-slow-on-nvidia-win-but-fast-on-linux/18510210)

It is a problem in the driver of `nVIDIA + Windows` only. Not AMD, not Intel, and not in linux.
But as the comment of @user2725937 says:

```
It is reported to nVIDIA and fixed in 331.xx beta drivers
```

Answer (score -1):

On your platform, **glFinish** and **clFinish** may not be required here. Try using **glFlush** and **clFlush** instead.

It really depends on the platform, as mentioned in the CL/GL extension specs. The specs says Finish is the only fully portable way, but faster alternatives may exist.

On Mac OS X for example, you need only **glFlushRenderAPPLE** and no **clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects** when switching from GL to CL, and then only **clFlush** and no **clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects** when switching back to GL.

Comment: How about doing neither and using a [fence sync object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sync_Object)?

Comment: I've just tried "flush" and it's same :( Slow things happen in clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects() and clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects(). "Finish" or "Flush" is not problem!

Comment: Nicol: But If I use "Sync Object". I still must call clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects(), so I think that's not solution :(

Comment: @Milan: The point that Eric and Nicol are trying to make is that both glFinish/clFinish are notoriously slow as they cause a complete stall. So basically, you explicitly make your GPU completely idle twice per frame.

Comment: glFinish and clFinish are necessary. opencl has to finish before opengl takes over and the other way around (clFlush only guaranties that the commands are issued not completed). I made sometime ago a small program using ocl and ogl (using the clFinish and glFinish) even with the kernel running I could reach sth around 500 fps on a GTX660Ti. So I'm almost sure that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: 40FPS is for 8K resolution, in Full HD it's running around 450FPS.

Comment: CaptainObvious: Did you use Frame buffer? I need to render to texture and then apply post-production in CL.

Comment: Problem is not with cl/glFinish() - they are fast. Slow are clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects() and clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects() !!!

Comment: @Eric Bainville: nice info about the specs that says clFinish is the only fully portable way. I overlooked this part. Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I was trying to learn how to use OpenCL a couple of years ago on an ATI card. I gave up and figured OpenCL was unusable. I have since tried CUDA on an NVidia card and had much better results. What I wonder then is if there is a vendor difference, as ATI drivers tend to be poor. What type of card do you have?

Comment: Joe: Nvidia GTS 450(Fermi). Maybe Kepler is better. The biggest problem is that I can make some optimalization, but this stupid GL/CL interop kills everything!