# OpenCL/GL Interop slow on nvidia/win but fast on linux?

Tags: performance, opengl, opencl, nvidia

**Below problem is fixed in nvidia's new driver release 331.xx, currently available as beta driver.**

**Thanks for all your comments!**

I have a multi-platform application that does many fragment operations and gpgpu stuff on OpenGL textures. The application makes heavy use of GL/CL interop, each texture may be bound to an OpenCL image and manipulated using CL kernels.

The problem is, the application runs fast on AMD cards, both Linux and Windows. On NVIDIA cards, it runs fast on Linux, but very slowly on Windows 7. Problem seems to be enqueueAcquireGLObjects and enqueueReleaseGLObjects. I have created a minimal sample, demonstrating the bad performance by simply:

1. Creating 2 OpenGL textures (1600x1200 pixel, RGBA float)
2. Creating 2 OpenCL images, sharing the 2 textures
3. repeatedly (50 times) acquire, release, finish

Results (mean time for executing acquire, release, finish)

- AMD HD 6980, Linux:    <0.1 ms
- AMD HD 6980, Win7:     <0.1 ms
- NVIDIA GTX590, Linux:  <0.1 ms
- NVIDIA GTX590, Win7 : **16.0 ms**

I have tried several different drivers from nvidia, from older 295.73 to current beta drivers 326.80, all showing the same behaviour.

My question now is, is the nvidia driver seriously broken or am I doing something wrong here? The code runs fast on linux, so it cant be a general problem with nvidia support for OpenCL. The code runs fast on AMD+Win, so it can not be a problem with my code being not optimized for Windows. Optimizing the code by, for example, changing the cl images to read/write-only is senseless, since performance hit is almost factor 30!

Below you can find the relevant code of my test case, I could provide full source code, too.

relevant code for context creation

```
{ // initialize GLEW
  glewInit();
}

{ // initialize CL Context, sharing GL Contet
  std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
  cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
  cl_context_properties cps[] = {
             CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR,(cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentContext(),
             CL_WGL_HDC_KHR,(cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentDC(),
             CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platforms[0]()),
             0};
  std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
  platforms[0].getDevices((cl_device_type)CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
  context_ = new cl::Context(devices, cps, NULL, this);
  queue_ = new cl::CommandQueue(*context_, devices[0]);
}
```

relevant code for creating textures and sharing CL images

```
width_ = 1600;
height_ = 1200;

float *data = new float[ 1600*1200*4 ];

textures_.resize(2);
glGenTextures(2, textures_.data());

for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures_[i]);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  // "data" pointer holds random/uninitialized data, do not care in this example
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F_ARB, width_,height_, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
}

delete data;
{ // create shared CL Images
#ifdef CL_VERSION_1_2
  clImages_.push_back(cl::ImageGL(*context_, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, textures_[0]));
  clImages_.push_back(cl::ImageGL(*context_, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, textures_[1]));
#else
  clImages_.push_back(cl::Image2DGL(*context_, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, textures_[0]));
  clImages_.push_back(cl::Image2DGL(*context_, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, textures_[1]));
#endif
}
```

relevant code for one acquire, release, finish cycle

```
try {
  queue_->enqueueAcquireGLObjects( &clImages_ );
  queue_->enqueueReleaseGLObjects( &clImages_ );
  queue_->finish();
} catch (cl::Error &e) {
  std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I can boil it down even more, just enqueueAcquireGLObjects, enqueueReleaseGLObjects will result in 16ms time on Win7. Have changed the question accordingly

Comment: Maybe the GL device is not the same as the CL device, which is causing a copy overhead? Just guessing...

Comment: I assume that if you use OpenGl you display something on the screen...For you test were you still displaying something too?

Comment: For the test, I am not rendering anything at all, GL context creation and texture allocation are the only calls to GL. GL and CL device could be different as the GTX590 is a dual chip card, yes. But i tried with GeForce cards ranging from 460 to 680.

Comment: the problem is fixed in latest beta drivers 331.xx! thanks for all your comments!

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna make the assumption that since you are using OpenGL, you display something on the screen after the OCL computation.

So based on that assumption, my first thought would be to check in the NVIDIA control panel if the VSync is enable and if yes to disable it and retest.

As far as I recall, the default options regarding vsync are different for AMD and NVIDIA; which would explain the difference between the two GPUs.

Just in case, here is a [post](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=928593) that explain how vsync can slow down the rendering.

Comment: Acquire/Release put consistency on the CL/GL objects prior to processing/render. So, it looks like rendering is not taking part at all. I would suggest that a hidden I/O is triggered for consistency.

Comment: As I said, it's based on the assumption that the OP displays something on the screen i.e. something is rendered on the screen. I had once a small video processing program running only at 60 fps on an powerful desktop NVIDIA GPU though on a mobile AMD It reached more than 100 fps. When I disable the vsync on the computer with the NVIDIA I reached more than 500 fps. BTW my screen's refreshing rate was 60Hz...

Comment: In my big application I display some textures on screen, that is correct, but in this test there is no rendering at all. I know about the problem with vsync as I had some issues with it some other time. On Windows i tried all the settings possible on the driver control panel, no help. I found out that i can even scale up the slowdown: if I acquire one texture = 8ms, two textures 16ms, 10 textures = 80ms. @DarkZeros hidden i/o sounds interesting what does it mean?

Comment: @user2725937 It means that  when you call the acquire() methods, the driver will copy/lock the OpenGL, in order to mantain consistency. Something similar to what happens with clEnqueueMapBuffer(). If the GL and CL are in different devices, or different drivers, etc.. this call "may" trigger some IO copy from the GL->CL or CL->GL buffers. Same as what happens when running 2 kernels in different devices one using the other result, there is a hidden IO copy that slows down the process.

Comment: @DarkZeros thanks for explaining. But even if there was a copy operation from a cl to a gl buffer, it should be much faster. 16ms for about 60mb

Comment: @DarkZeros thanks. But even if there was a copy operation from a cl to a gl buffer, it should be much faster. 16ms for about 60mb of data is not plausible, even if nvidia would have to freeze gl state, switch context, whatever they are doing - only on windows? I could copy the data to host memory and back to GPU faster. I'd love to file a bug to nvidia but can not find out how. I found a post  http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/7899-OpenCL-OpenGL-Problems-clEnqueue-Acquire-Release-GLObjects possibly related problem and nvidia told him to use cuda?! nobody else with same prob?

Comment: @user2725937 Then it is probably a nVIDIA problem on how they handle this GL/CL context sharing. You could try to avoid the problem, use something different instead?

Comment: I reported the problem to nvidia and it is indeed fixed in their new driver release 331.xx, currently available as beta driver.